# Am I allowed to directly fix a typo about experiment results during camera-ready?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have recently received acceptance notification from a top-tier AI conference. When I prepare my camera-ready version I realised that I wrongly pasted the variance for the cell before to the current cell.

E.g. 
                         Dataset1         Dataset2
Model1          60±0.03         82±0.35

Model2          62±0.04         84±**0.04**

Where the variance for Model2 on Dataset2 should be **0.32** but I wrongly paste it to 0.04 unintentionally. This wrong variance does not change my conclusion, but I want to be accurate about the experiment results. I would like to fix this before submitting camera-ready version but not sure if this is allowed.

Should I email programme committee to explain this or I could simply make the change and submit the new version (worrying for this change involves experiment results)?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the whole point of reviewing things for a camera-ready version to give a final check like this?

Comment: Yes, that is why I want to change it. What makes me to ask is that can I simply make the change and submit, or I should explain to the committee given this involves experimental results.

Comment: Is there not a place to explain changes with your resubmission?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Editorial changes are always possible as long as they do not affect the *interpretation* of things. So if the number you previously had was crucial to the interpretation of the experiment -- for example, if you stated that the temperature at which a material becomes superconducting was 280K -- then you probably shouldn't change it when you realized that it should really have been 28.0K because that would fundamentally change the message. On the other hand, if this was just an otherwise unimportant number in a table, then you can change typos, grammar errors, etc.

Of course, this sort of thing should not have happened, and it would be worth your time to walk once around the block and think about how it happened and how you should change your work practices to make sure it doesn't happen again.